# Deleting empty rows on different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little bit a problem, which I can't figure out. (It seems to be pretty simple taking into account functions used).

Short description: I have a code that enters file and copy some columns from there to DestWbk, sheets' name is "sheet1". This is just a part of the code, but the data is copied and now I need to clear it from rows with empty values in specific column.

```
DestWbk=ThisWorkbook

        check = "alpha"
        checkcol = DestWbk.Sheets("sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=check, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
        MsgBox (checkcol)
           Set column_range = DestWbk.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(checkcol).EntireColumn

            If DestWbk.Worksheets("sheet1").WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(DestWbk.Worksheets("sheet1").column_range) > 0 Then
            DestWbk.Worksheets("sheet1").column_range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim f as range, sht1 as worksheet, column_range as range, check

Set sht1 = DestWbk.Sheets("sheet1")

check = "alpha"
Set f= sht1.Cells.Find(What:=check, LookIn:=xlValues)

'make sure you got a match from Find before proceeding
if not f is nothing then
    Set column_range = sht1.usedrange.columns(f.column)
    on error resume next 'ignore error if no blanks
    column_range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    on error goto 0      'stop ignoring errors
End If
```

Comment: Tim, can you please explain the following issue? For most of the cases, this code works fine, but sometimes when values are insterted as text, this function fails. Is there any way to sort it ouy?

Comment: What values are inserted as text?